# While attempting to show user specific data throughout the application, how can I minimize the usage of Firebase resources?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm working on an angular application, using Firebase for persistence. I have multiple locations on the page, each show user specific info (i.e. profile pic, current logged in status, etc).

I am struggling to come up with a "good" solution that will allow me to embrace the 3 way data data-binding, and maintain a proper separation of concerns.

For a very specific instance of my problem. I have a HeaderMessagesCtrl, which pulls a list of messages from firebase at /users/x/messages. The messages, which contain a fromUserId, are bound to $scope.messages;

I have an angular view that does ng-repeat on the messages collection, and for each row, I would like to use the fromUserId to determine the user's logged in status, profilePicUri, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/brkAq/5/

```
function HeaderMessagesCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.messages = [
    {fromUserId: 1},
    {fromUserId: 2}
  ]; 

  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.messages.push({fromUserId: 3});
  }, 1500);    
}
```

The above fiddle shows a sample collection that then gets modified at a later time. Hopefully this can assist to provide an example solution.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I was asked to suggest a pattern, so below is the first thing to come to mind.

I was thinking of creating a watch on the scope variable, that contained the array that firebase will be updating. This watch would reach out to the UserService to obtain the profilePicUri, and thus create a scope array that was more like a view model instead of an exact replica of the data in firebase.

The other option was to create a user-profile-box widget, which you could provide the user id, and it would figure out the uri from the UserService, and use those details to make the widget html, etc.

Either way, my struggle is the "relationship-less" nature of firebase.

Comment: Hey, Chris--I don't think I understand your question. Could you add an example of a pattern you've considered using (and what you don't like about it)?

Comment: I added some more data, thanks for reaching out.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand either but if you haven't read [this](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html#join) it might help. Maybe you should do something like that whenever you detect a `'child_added'` event on the `users/x/messages` ref.

Comment: @hiattp thanks for the link.. The post that helped me the most was https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html

Comment: Hey Chris, I'm still not entirely clear on what your question is. You've loaded a list of messages, but would like to retrieve some other data for a specific User who authored a specific message? You can create multiple angularFire() three-way bindings for each data point you want to render.